# Where shoul I store private/public keys and how should I share it?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, keys, key-exchange

I'm new in terms of encryption and I have to encrypt the data between two Java Spring applications, one have serves as MVC framework and other as Web Service, I'm implementing an asymmetric encryption by generating the private and public key with RSA at the beginning of the deployment cycle and saving the keys in binary files locally in the hard drive but I’m not sure if that is the best way of doing it, and then I have to share the public keys between the two projects automatically but I don’t know how should I do this, I was planning to exchange the keys by sending a petition to the Web Service.

I'm using the `KeyPairGenerator` class to get a `KeyPair` and writing the `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` objects to local disc.

Comment: Do you have a communication channel between the servers that can be assumed to not tamper with data transported? Would the loss of a private key (in terms of availability) be a major problem? Do you require user / admin interaction at application startup? Do you have a HSM / TPM on the server running these services?

Comment: @SEJPM The spring MVC application is consuming the Spring boot application with REST petitions via POST, but no, I don't have a secure communication channel between the servers, yeah It would be a major problem, No, I don't require user/admin interaction, I don't have a HSM/TPM server running. I can only generate public/private keys in both Spring applications but don't know how to do the public key distribution